# how to get id of image right after adding it to image gallery of product?

Tags: magento-1.9, gallery

I need somehow to get id of product right after it addition to gallery of product, i am trying this code, but still ID is null for some reason:

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageToAdd,
        array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),
        false,
        false);

$product->save();

$items = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

foreach($items as $productImage) {
    if(basename($productImage->getFile()) === basename($imageToAdd)){
        $uploadedImagesIds[] = $productImage->getId(); // it gives NULL
        break;
    }
}
```

Althrough I've called `$product->save()` method it still gives me `null` on `$productImage->getId()`;

Is it possible to retrieve id of image added to gallery somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but I think if you call `load` again after calling `save` it might work.

So after `$product->save();` do this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$items = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
//then your foreach loop here
```

Here is why I think this.

The `getMediaGalleryImages` method looks like this:

```
public function getMediaGalleryImages()
{
    if(!$this->hasData('media_gallery_images') && is_array($this->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
        $images = new Varien_Data_Collection();
        foreach ($this->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
            if ($image['disabled']) {
                continue;
            }
            $image['url'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
            $image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
            $image['path'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
            $images->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
        }
        $this->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
    }

    return $this->getData('media_gallery_images');
}
```

Look a the first if statement. The images are retrieved again from the db only if inside the product instance `_data['media_gallery_images']` is not set or `$this->getMediaGallery('images')` is not an array.
Since you already called `load` on the product before adding the image `_data['media_gallery_images']` is always set, so the code is not executed. You only get the images you previously had and the image you added.
But the image you just added does not have an id because the method that is called to actually assign the image does not return the id: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media::addImage`.
Reloading the product instance again should get you the id.

Small note: I think `save` is not really needed, but not sure.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much it worked ! Tried without $product->save(); but it's not worked, so seems like this is required.